# how to load page b using expander in page a?

Tags: atk4, agiletoolkit

as you know, we can use this code in index and it works truely...
it loads the page_userreferals...

```
$g->addColumn('expander','userreferals',"Users List");
```

but when I use it in other pages, an error occurs...

```
Exception_PathFinder, code: 0

Additional information:

    file: desk\Page\userreferals.php
    type: page
    attempted_locations:
        0: C:/wamp/www/test/page/desk/userreferals.php
...
```

the problem is that the agile tookit search for the requested page in subdirectory. how can we change that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
$grid->columns['userreferals']['page'] = $this->api->url('b');
```

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
class page_main extends Page {
    function page_bla() {
        ...
        $g->addColumn('expander','userreferals',"Users List");
        ....
    }
    function page_bla_userreferals() {
    }

}
```